# Capture console output from existing process(es) to file

Tags: linux, io-redirection, console

We have a requirement to troubleshoot an existing system running Busybox, we have Telnet access. It would be helpful to log the system's console output (ideally the last *n* lines of it) to a file for debugging.

There's plenty of examples on redirecting the stdout/stderr of a command to a file *at the point of invocation*, but I can't find anything conclusive on capturing output from a *running process or processes*.

It seems like we should perhaps be able to capture/redirect from `/proc/<PID>/fd/1` but searching suggests this is not possible, and I haven't managed to find an incantation to make it work.

Being a small embedded system we can't install more packages, so if it can't be done with basic command-line kung-fu we'll have to go back to the drawing board.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html it appears that syslogd writes to /var/log/messages (default). Would that be helpful? Of course that would assume syslogd is installed.

Comment: Use `script` on the machine you telnet _from_.

Comment: One way or another you need to call `ptrace`. You will need nonstandard tools, but it can be a tiny C program, or GDB.

Comment: I realise this is a possible duplicate question, but the accepted answer to the duplicate is pretty much a dead "no", with very little else by way of exploration of options or other approaches. Seems a bit defeatist to me.

Answer (score -1):

You can. First SIGSTOP the process you are interested in, then change /proc/[pid]/fd/x to whatever you need (you can symbolic link it to a tty or a file), and then SIGCONT the process. now it will write its stdout and stderr to whatever tty or file you specified.

Comment: You can't modify `/proc/<pid>/fd/1`, at least not directly.

Comment: @Giles. yes you can, you can use the "p dup2" command in gdb to manipulate file descriptors on a running process. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin

Comment: That's completely different. You aren't modifying the file under `/proc`, you're causing the process to open a different file, which is of course reflected in the `/proc` interface.

Comment: @Gilles: "*completely* different?" Really? Not. you're splitting hairs at this point.